# grocery crud change default theme

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter. I am using grocery crud. I want to change the default theme of grocery crud except "$crud->set_theme('datatables');".
by using this it is necessary to change in all functions. but i want to change at only one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changing the default theme of grocery crud 
go to

```
application->config->grocery_crud.php
```

and change the name of theme

```
$config['grocery_crud_default_theme'] = 'name of your theme';
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: after initializing the object i.e
$crud=new grocery_CRUD();
Set your theme below this line as
**$crud->set_theme('datatables');**